# jQuery mobile 1.3 panel on android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using the new panel widget from jQuery mobile. But i think it has a bug. I can't scroll inside the panel if its content is bigger then the actual "content".

To see what I mean, please check out [this](http://movsky.org/jqm.html) on an Android device and try to scroll inside the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed with jquery-mobile 1.3 RC1.

Answer (score 0):

you can add two `attributes` in `css` to fix the `scroll`

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" style=" height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">
```

I hope this work in Android, Please try.

Comment: then you have to use scrollview() function to make scroll by your self.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/pnswebmailmobile/source/browse/trunk/web/assets/js/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js?r=391

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear `ui-panel-inner` and add `overflow: scroll` to `ui-panel`

```
.ui-panel { 
   width: 17em; 
   min-height: 100%; 
   border-width: 0; 
   position: absolute !important; 
   overflow: scroll !important; 
   top: 0; 
   display: block; 
   padding: 0 !important; 
   margin: 0 !important; 
}

.ui-panel-inner:after { 
   content: '.'; 
   height: 0; 
   font-size: 0; 
   clear: both; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
}
```